# numeric or value error: character string buffer too small - PHP + Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

Below is my procedure

```
NOBL_TEC_TEST_PROC(v1 number,v2 out number)
```

my model function

```
public function testProc()
{
    $result = '';
    $db = "orcl";
    $conn = oci_connect("***", "****", $db);
    $sql = 'begin NOBL_TEC_TEST_PROC(222, :seqno); end;';
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':seqno', $result);
    oci_execute($stmt);

    return $result;

}
```

if I give the IN value <10 it is working fine, but when I try to give IN value >10 it is giving following error.

```
<b>Warning</b>:  oci_execute(): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 1 in....
```

How can I fix this? Any help? Thanks

Comment: You need to change the procedure.... you're assigning one of your parameters to a local variable in that procedure (or in something that procedure calls etc). The local variable does not have the correct datatype to accept what you are passing... you're going to have to change it.

Comment: How should I change the procedure? am a php developer so I dont really know..

Comment: If you post the procedure then someone will be able to help... changing it might have knock on effects though so it's best to ask the person responsible for it.

Answer (score 7):

I Know its a little late, but you need to add your buffer size to your oci_bind_by_name

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':seqno', $result,2000);
```

This should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

possibly in the db the procedure parameter IN has parameter VARCHAR2(1) or something like that.

A number above 10 is two characters so an error is raised.

You should simply access the source of the Oracle Procedure, change the type of the parameter in the header and body of the procedure and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: this error was raised also when a parameter was declared as "IN OUT". Since we use refcursor to retrieve the result such declaration was in fact not needed and was changed to "IN" only. This resolved our issue.